# Problem with  the popup/notification in Android?

Tags: android

I have created an activity in which I have created a progress bar as follows, and I have written the Notification but it's not working.  Notification occurs at top corner of the screen sometimes.  I want that Notification as a message box in the middle of the screen.  How to achieve it?  My activity code as follows:

```
public class oddg extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    int increment;
    int maximum ;
    private NotificationManager mManager;

     private static final int APP_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);
        Button startbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
        startbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mManager = (NotificationManager)   
           getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {

        // get the increment value from the text box
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.increment);
        // convert the text value to a integer
        increment = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        // set the progress to be horizontal
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        // reset the bar to the default value of 0
        dialog.setProgress(0);

        // get the maximum value
        EditText max = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.maximum);
        // convert the text value to a integer
          maximum = Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString());
        // set the maximum value
        dialog.setMax(maximum);
        // display the progressbar
        dialog.show();

        // create a thread for updating the progress bar
        Thread background = new Thread (new Runnable() {
           public void run() 
           {
               try 
               {

           // enter the code to be run while displaying the progressbar.
               // This example is just going to increment the progress bar:
              // So keep running until the progress value reaches maximum value
            while(dialog.getProgress()<= dialog.getMax()) 
              {
                       // wait 500ms between each update
                       Thread.sleep(500);
                       // active the update handler
                     progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                   }
               }
               catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) 
               {
                   // if something fails do something smart
               }
           }
        });
        // start the background thread
        background.start();
     }

 // handler for the background updating
    Handler progressHandler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            if(dialog.getProgress()== dialog.getMax())
            {
                Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"Click here", System.currentTimeMillis());

                notification.setLatestEventInfo(oddg.this,"App Name","Description of the notification",PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY, getIntent(), CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY));

            }
            dialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this

```
notificationMgr =  context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,    
               new Intent(ctx, myActClassName.class), 0);

Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, someText, System.currentTimeMillis());

notification.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, title, contentText, contentIntent);  
int HELLO_ID = 10;  
notificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

For Status bar Notification check this
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
http://javainnovations.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-send-message-to-status-bar-in.html

Comment: thanks..that means should i make one class and put this code on its OnCreate()..m i rght???

Comment: Up to  setLatestEventInfo will be in onCreate   and the notify is when the actual event that requires notification takes place - hope that helps